# mapear un array de observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Tengo un servicio que me devuelve de un webAPI un array de entidades con estas propiedades

[image: propiedades originales]

Pero en mi Front de Angular yo trabajo con esta clase

```
export interface Proyecto{
 id:string;
 descripcion:string;
 clienteId:string;
 clienteNombre:string;
}
```

Con lo cual intento mapear el resultado del servicio a esta entidad

```
getProyectos(): Observable<Proyecto[]> {
return this.http.get<Proyecto[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/proyectosSAP`)
  .pipe(
    map(proyectos=>
      proyectos.map(
        ...proyecto,
          id:proyecto.prjCode,
          descripcion:proyecto.u_extname2,
          clienteId:proyecto.u_CardCode,
          clienteNombre:proyecto.u_CardName
      ) as Proyecto
    ),
    tap(data => console.log('SAPService-getProyectos(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
 }
```

Pero me da error

[image: error]

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: la función `Array.map` espera una función como parámetro, similar al operador `map` de Rxjs, pero le estás pasando algo que no es una función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal está en `proyectos.map(...)`

El método `map` de un array, espera como argumento una función de mapeo, del tipo `Array.map((elemento) => { return elementoMapeado; })`

Por tanto en tu caso tienes que modificar esa línea de la siguiente manera.

```
proyectos.map((proyecto) => {
  return {
    id:proyecto.prjCode,
    descripcion:proyecto.u_extname2,
    clienteId:proyecto.u_CardCode,
    clienteNombre:proyecto.u_CardName
  };
})
```

---

Otro problema que veo en tu código, es que tienes marcado como `Proyecto[]` el tipo de retorno de la petición http, cuando los objetos que recibes de la petición según dices no se ajustan a la interface Proyecto.

Tendrás que crearte otra interface para marcar correctamente el tipo de retorno, o en su defecto marcarlo como `any[]`, ya que sino al intentar acceder a las propiedades `prjCode,u_extname2,...` desde la función de mapeo probablemente también  te lo marcará como error.

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo las indicaciones de @akotech

He creado una nueva interface para obtener lo que recibo del servicio

```
export interface ProyectoSAP{
 prjCode:string;
 u_extname2:string;
 u_CardCode:string;
 u_CardName:string;
```

}

y ahora tengo esto funcionando

```
getProyectos(): Observable<Proyecto[]> {
 return this.http.get<ProyectoSAP[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/proyectosSAP`)
  .pipe(
    map(proyectos=>
      proyectos.map((proyecto)=>{
        return{
          id:proyecto.prjCode,
          descripcion:proyecto.u_extname2,
          clienteId:proyecto.u_CardCode,
          clienteNombre:proyecto.u_CardName
        };
      }
    )
    ),
    tap(data => console.log('SAPService-getProyectos(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```